# Custom Attribute + validating permissions with query string?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0, query-string, ninject, custom-attributes

I have a certain part of my site that checks if the logged on user can access the id of a record (Report id), if so they can view the content on that page. There can be various different types of users/companies that will view the content.

What is the best practise for writing a custom attribute that will check if user can access the id? Should I pass in a query string? Note that the id will come from the route/url.

E.g. Report id = 678.
urls:

- /Report/678/Detail
- /Report/678/Progress/Staged
- /Report/678/TaskManager/78/
- /Report/678/Participants

usage of code below

```
[ReportAuthorizationAttribute ())] //get query string yourself
[ReportAuthorizationAttribute (Request.Querystring["reportid"))] //this does not look possible to do???
```

//Code that will be added to the **base controller** for this area

```
public class ReportAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    /// <summary>
    /// inject via Ninject - there must be a better way? Using service locator?
    /// </summary>
    [Inject]
    public readonly IReportRepo _repo { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    public readonly IUserSession _user { get; set; }

    private int _reportid;

    public ReportAuthorizationAttribute()
        : base()
    { //*Is this way the best way?*
     _reportid= Int32.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["reportid"]);
    }

    public ReportAuthorizationAttribute(params int reportid)
        : base()
    {
        _reportid = reportid;
    }

    public ReportAuthorizationAttribute(params string reportid)
        : base()
    {
        _reportid= Int32.Parse(reportid);
    }


    public bool AlwaysAllowLocalRequests = false;


    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new NoAccessException("httpContext is null");

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            throw new NoAccessException("unauthorized user");

        var companyid = _user.GetCurrentUser().CompanyID;
        if (AlwaysAllowLocalRequests && _repo.IsCompanyParticipantInReport(_reportid, companyid))
            return true;

        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> //*Is this way the best way?*
>
> `_reportid= Int32.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["reportid"]);`

If you use routing, `reportid` won't be part of the query string. You need to fetch it from the route:

```
var reportId = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["reportId"];
```

Also don't use HttpContext.Current in your action filter constructor. Use it only inside the `AuthorizeCore` method:

```
public class ReportAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public readonly IReportRepo _repo { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public readonly IUserSession _user { get; set; }

    public bool AlwaysAllowLocalRequests = false;

    private string _reportId;

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        _reportId = filterContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["reportId"] as string;
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            return false;

        if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return false;

        int reportId;
        if (!int.TryParse(_reportId, out reportId))
            return false;

        var companyid = _user.GetCurrentUser().CompanyID;
        return AlwaysAllowLocalRequests && 
               _repo.IsCompanyParticipantInReport(reportId, companyid));
    }
}
```

Comment: Query string and route data, I am not sure what the difference is, all I know that it will be in my url, I have set up the routes so that if I say /Report/{reportid}/Details, You are saying this is accessible in route data and not query string? Sorry, I really dont know!

Comment: @Harron, a query string is what comes after the `?` in a url. For example: `/Report/Detail?reportId=678`. You could use `Request.QueryString` in this case. But in your example reportId is part of the route definition: `/Report/{reportid}/Details`, so you cannot use QueryString to fetch it. You should use `RouteData` as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, This line however does not work, I dont seem to have access to RequestContext: httpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values[""]

Comment: @Haroon, oh you are not using .NET 4.0? That explains it. I have eupdated my post.

Comment: thank you! btw, do you think that doing a permissions check like this is ok/ good practise? This is the only way I could think of to make it generic, else I am repeating stuff all over the place...

Comment: @Haroon, yes it is good. The only problem is that if inside your controller action you needed to access for example the report (assuming the user was authorized) you would probably perform an additional database request (the same in fact as the one in the filter). The way I solve this is to use a custom model binder instead of an authorize attribute. This way the Report object is directly used as action argument.

Comment: I did this initially then changed to this approach, I mean I have seperated out the actual report table from report participant anyway, so I am accessing one table for permission and another table to actually get the data...